# Using inview function with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div, with a paragraph within it. I want to use jquery to only show that paragraph then the div is within the viewport- for this I am using a plugin. However, because the paragraph is initially hidden - the height of 'mydiv' is 0 and not being found by the plugin, therefore the function is never executed. Anyone got a suggestion for a way around this?

```
<div class = "mydiv">
    <p> Hide this content </p>
</div>
```

```
.mydiv p { display:none; }
```

```
//JQuery plugin 
if $(".mydiv").on('inview',function(event,isInView){
       p.show();
}
```

Comment: While I'm not familiar with the plugin, I can guarantee that using an `if` with an `on` isn't correct, not to mention the few syntax errors I'm seeing. Your code says `if (event binding) { ... }` - it doesn't make sense. Also, an element's height doesn't affect it's ability to be "found". This question needs some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector doesn't look up the dom element by the height exactly doesn't care at all about height. You could override the height by css( "height", "10px" ).

jQuery show is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block" ), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially.

jQuery hide is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline and is hidden then shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

Your code is not correct either. I guess it should be like this, without knowing exactly what the purpose is:

```
 $(".mydiv").on('inview',function(event,isInView) {
           p.show();
 }); // Do not use if statement
```